# HTML/CSS - How to make div's fit each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my div's fit each other like on pinterest.com. Right now my html/css is like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
    <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
    <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
</div>

#content{ float:left;width:1000px; }
.box{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
}
```

.box can be whatever height the post is. So I want my div's to fit no matter what height it has. Just like pinterest.com :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found this plugin by using jQuery:

http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Answer (score 3):

think in terms of columns

css

```
 <style type="text/css">

  .container { display:block;width:100%; /* or whatever you are using */ }
  .col { display:block;float:left;width:25%; }
  .box { display:block; padding:10px;margin:10px;}
  .clear { display:block; clear:both;line-height:0;}


</style>
```

markup

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="col">

  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>

 </div>

 <div class="col">

  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>

 </div>

 <div class="col">

  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>

 </div>

 <div class="col">

  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>
  <div class="box">my content, which can be xx px heigh.</div>

 </div>

 <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```